How do I get rid of all line breaks in a cell by means of the SUBSTITUTE() function?
I have a text with line breaks inside cell "A1":
abc
def

This shall become:
abc\r\ndef

I want to have those line break signs "\r\n" in there, my aim is to get SQL queries as a one-liner so that I can put them in a derived column "query" as a documentation of what is the full query if it is not split into many SSIS boxes)
But if I run:
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"\r\n")

..I only get:
abc
\r\ndef

Thus, it finds the point of the line break in one row, but it does not replace the line break between the two rows.
I could not get further with:

Remove all manual line breaks in Excel sheet,
How to remove line breaks (carriage return) in Excel?,
and How can I remove line breaks from a string column in an ETL? shows the REGEX_REPLACE() function for SQL, but I need an Excel function.

How can I replace the line breaks in a cell with the SUBSTITUTE() function?

You need to replace:

CHAR(10) (LF, line feed) with "\r\n"
and CHAR(13) (CR, carriage return) with an empty string "".

That is why you need to run the function twice:
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"\r\n");CHAR(13);"")

This reaches:
abc\r\ndef

More on SSIS (does not answer the question)
In a Derived Column in SSIS, I had to escape the squared brackets and the backslashes by doubling them. This can also be done in Excel:
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"\r\n");CHAR(13);"");"[";"[[");"]";"]]");"\";"\\")

